# Spring boot localise every response parameter from RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, localization, internationalization, jackson

I am trying to localize almost every parameter in the response of each API in my project.

I have figured out that we can do something like this in spring boot:

```
MessageSourceAccessor accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, locale);
return accessor.getMessage(code);
```

and keep the code versus localized message mapping in `messages_en.properties`, `messages_fr.properties` etc.

But for my application I specifically have two requirements:

- I want to separate this logic from my business logic i.e., I don't want to write localization logic in each and every controller.
- I want to try it at each and every response parameter for all the response through the server, maybe while Jackson is converting objects to string or after conversion to JSON.

Is there a way in spring boot to achieve this or are there any libraries available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. Instead of using String for fields, I am using a custom class like `LocalizedText`:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LocalizedText {

    private String text;

}
```

For serialization, I have created a Deserializer `LocalizedTextSerailizer`, something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

@Component
 public class LocalizedTextSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalizedText> {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 619043384446863988L;

    @Autowired
    I18nUtil messages;

    public LocalizedTextSerializer() {
        super(LocalizedText.class);
    }

    public LocalizedTextSerializer(Class<LocalizedText> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalizedText value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(messages.get(value.getText()));
    }

}
```

`I18nUtil`:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException;
import org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class I18nUtil {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String get(String code) {
        try {
            MessageSourceAccessor accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.getDefault());
            return accessor.getMessage(code);
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException nsme) {
            log.info("Message not found in localization: " + code);
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

This pretty much serves the purpose, I don't have to mess up with the business logic and I can localize any parameter for any response in the application.

Note:

1. Here I18nUtil, returns the same code if it couldn't find any message in the message.properties.
2. Default locale is used in I18nUtil, for demonstration.